# laravel apache setup rootdocument

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to setup my laravel application on different server centos 7 running httpd

my old configuration on other servers: i always setup document root to be in "laravelProjectDir/public"
however in this server i've tried the following:

here is my apache config file:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost subdomain.domain.com:443>
 ServerName subdomain.domain.com
 ServerAdmin email@gmail.com

 DocumentRoot /home/MyUser/public_html/subDomain/public2
 <Directory /home/MyUser/public_html/subDomain/public2/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all
  Require all granted
 </Directory>
 LogLevel debug
 ErrorLog /home/MyUser/log-subDomain.txt
 CustomLog /home/MyUser/customlog-subDomain.txt combined
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.domain.com/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.domain.com/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.domain.com/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

============================================================
**Option 1**
public2 which is Laravel root directory is the Apache RootDocument

accessing website from web browser with following link: https://subdomain.domain.com**/public** works good (all files in public are shown + routes work)

accessing website from web browser with following link: https://subdomain.domain.com/ routes works but all files inside public now doesn't show (ERROR 404)

==============================================================
**Option 2**

this is the option that always worked for me on my previous servers but not on this server.

public2/public <-- laravelRoot/public/ directory is the Apache RootDocument

/etc/httpd/sites-enabled < changed the following lines:

```
 DocumentRoot /home/MyUser/public_html/subDomain/public2/public
 <Directory /home/MyUser/public_html/subDomain/public2/public/>
```

result:

```
500 Internal Server Error
```

Apache Log:

```
[Sat Mar 06 11:32:42.550524 2021] [core:alert] [pid 6173] [client 109.161.x.x:8789] /home/myUser/public_html/subDomain/public2/.htaccess: Options not allowed here, referer: https://subdomain.domain.com/public/home
[Sat Mar 06 11:32:42.550695 2021] [ssl:debug] [pid 6173] ssl_engine_io.c(993): [client 109.161.x.x:8789] AH02001: Connection closed to child 1 with standard shutdown (server subdomain.domain.com:443)
[Sat Mar 06 11:32:44.626866 2021] [ssl:debug] [pid 6174] ssl_engine_kernel.c(225): [client 109.161.x.x:8790] AH02034: Initial (No.1) HTTPS request received for child 2 (server subdomain.domain.com:443)
[Sat Mar 06 11:32:44.627360 2021] [core:alert] [pid 6174] [client 109.161.x.x:8790] /home/myUser/public_html/subDomain/public2/.htaccess: Options not allowed here
[Sat Mar 06 11:32:44.627537 2021] [ssl:debug] [pid 6174] ssl_engine_io.c(993): [client 109.161.x.x:8790] AH02001: Connection closed to child 2 with standard shutdown (server subdomain.domain.com:443)
[Sat Mar 06 11:32:45.126934 2021] [ssl:debug] [pid 6176] ssl_engine_kernel.c(225): [client 109.161.x.x:8791] AH02034: Initial (No.1) HTTPS request received for child 4 (server subdomain.domain.com:443), referer: https://subdomain.domain.com/
[Sat Mar 06 11:32:45.127497 2021] [core:alert] [pid 6176] [client 109.161.x.x:8791] /home/myUser/public_html/subDomain/public2/.htaccess: Options not allowed here, referer: https://subdomain.domain.com/
[Sat Mar 06 11:32:45.127686 2021] [ssl:debug] [pid 6176] ssl_engine_io.c(993): [client 109.161.x.x:8791] AH02001: Connection closed to child 4 with standard shutdown (server subdomain.domain.com:443)
```

what is the issue here. why Apache cant allow options while I'm already setting it up with .htaccess and `AllowOverride all` ?